# raspistill returning file not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4, raspistill

I am trying to use the 64 bit version of raspbian (which can be found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=117&t=275370

I downloaded it, installed everything, ran my updates and then switched on the camera.   But when I try to run it, the PI just gives back

```
bash: /opt/vc/bin/raspistill: No such file or directory
```

When I do a ls, I can see the directory fine:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/opt/vc/bin $ ls
containers_check_frame_int    containers_test       dtoverlay-pre  raspiyuv
containers_datagram_receiver  containers_test_bits  dtparam        tvservice
containers_datagram_sender    containers_test_uri   edidparser     vcdbg
containers_dump_pktfile       containers_uri_pipe   mmal_vc_diag   vcgencmd
containers_rtp_decoder        dtmerge               raspistill     vchiq_test
containers_stream_client      dtoverlay             raspivid       vcmailbox
containers_stream_server      dtoverlay-post        raspividyuv    vcsmem
```

and when I look at the permissions, there are read/execute permissions for everyone:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 142397 Nov  1 16:25 raspistill
```

Im at a bit of a loss here - the file is right there, so why is it not being found when I try to call it from the command line?

Comment: Try running `type raspistill` to see what is actually run when you execute `raspistill` When you find what is actually run, trying running `file XYZ` on that to see if it is a script. If it is, try running it with `bash -xv THATSCRIPT` to follow its execution.

Comment: any update? also having this problem, attached below is separate commands and their output

Comment: ubuntu64@ubuntu:~/dev/raspberry-pi-userland$ type raspistill
raspistill is hashed (/opt/vc/bin/raspistill)

Comment: ubuntu64@ubuntu:~/dev/raspberry-pi-userland$ file /opt/vc/bin/raspistill
/opt/vc/bin/raspistill: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.1.9, with debug_info, not stripped

Comment: ubuntu64@ubuntu:~/dev/raspberry-pi-userland$ raspistill
-bash: /opt/vc/bin/raspistill: No such file or directory

Comment: were you able to resolve that issue?

Comment: I have the same problem on my raspberry pi 4 64

Comment: I upgraded kernel from 5.4 to 5.10 and got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like MMAL userland still (at the time of writing this) [has some unresolved issues](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1729089#p1729089) with 64bit raspberry pi OS, so it is disabled.

However, one can use [docker or cherry-build 32bit packages](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=275372&start=600#p1807155) as workarounds.